# Meta Cloud API is triggering every webhook for multiple Apps

Tags: facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I am currently facing an issue with the Meta Cloud API and WhatsApp Business API and I'm seeking some guidance.

**Issue Description:**

I have a WhatsApp chatbot for customers, and to facilitate testing and development, I've set up three different environments (stages). Each stage has its own test number and is associated with a separate app using the Meta Cloud API and WhatsApp Business API. Every app is connected to its unique webhook and is subscribed to the 'messages' field.

However, I am encountering an unexpected behavior where every webhook is receiving events from all other numbers, not just its corresponding number.

**Setup Details:**

For each app, I have the following configuration in the meta developer web app:

> **Quickstart Configuration:**
> To get alerted when you receive a message or when a message's status has changed, a Webhooks endpoint is set up for each app.

*Callback URL:* Each app has a different callback URL, something like https://.....com/webhook.

*Verify token:* Different for each app

**What actually happens:**

Despite having distinct endpoints and configurations for each app, messages intended for one stage are being received by the webhooks of the other stages as well.

Object received from Meta Cloud API when I send "hi" to the test number – gets delivered to all three webhooks:

```
{
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "id_1",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                        "metadata": {
                            "display_phone_number": "test_stage_phone_no",
                            "phone_number_id": "test_stage_phone_no_id"
                        },
                        "contacts": [
                            {
                                "profile": {
                                    "name": "Leon"
                                },
                                "wa_id": "my_phone_number"
                            }
                        ],
                        "messages": [
                            {
                                "from": "my_phone_number",
                                "id": "wamid.HBgNNDk...",
                                "timestamp": "1704481181",
                                "text": {
                                    "body": "hi"
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": "messages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Object received from Meta Cloud API when I send "hi" to the production number – gets delivered to all three webhooks:

```
{
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "id_2",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                        "metadata": {
                            "display_phone_number": "prod_stage_phone_no",
                            "phone_number_id": "prod_stage_phone_no_id"
                        },
                        "contacts": [
                            {
                                "profile": {
                                    "name": "Leon"
                                },
                                "wa_id": "my_phone_number"
                            }
                        ],
                        "messages": [
                            {
                                "from": "my_phone_number",
                                "id": "wamid.HBgNN...",
                                "timestamp": "1704482444",
                                "text": {
                                    "body": "hi"
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": "messages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As a temporary workaround, in my webhook, I am checking the WhatsApp Business ID from which the message originates and filtering out messages that don't match the Business ID associated with that stage. However, I believe there should be a way to ensure each webhook only receives messages for its specific app.

**Questions:**

Has anyone else experienced this issue with the Meta Cloud API and WhatsApp Business API?

Is there a configuration step I might be missing that would ensure each webhook only receives messages intended for its associated app?
Are there any best practices or additional settings I should consider to isolate the webhook events to their respective apps?

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same issue and still looking for the resolve
I would like dedicated webhooks triggered of course. Will appreciate if you had a chance to resolve the issue

Comment: @Animus Great to hear I am not the only one. Still have not found a fix unfortunately. I submitted a support request but naturally I never received a reply.

Comment: What we plan is to put apps under different pages, but that'll be a really long way.
I'm trying to spot a difference in requests and see if we can distinguish the apps meanwhile. If I get some progress - I'll message you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure yet if that is a bug or a feature, but there is a workaround to fix this.

**Approach we used**
You want to take the message object from the webhook, and there are 2 fields that will allow you distinguish the source app from the additional triggers.

```
{
  "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
  "entry": [{
      "id": "WHATSAPP_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID",
      "changes": [{
          "value": {
              "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
              "metadata": {
                  "display_phone_number": "PHONE_NUMBER",
                  "phone_number_id": "PHONE_NUMBER_ID"
              },
              # specific Webhooks payload            
          },
          "field": "messages"
        }]
    }]
}
```

You can use WHATSAPP_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID or PHONE_NUMBER_ID(if your apps have different numbers as in our case) These 2 elements will be constant for the app you send message from. Just save one of them on your side, and check if message comes from the desired app to handle it later.

**Another approach**
This wasn't a good workaround for us, but it is possible to have an app per business page. With this setup you will ensure 1 endpoint per whole business account and you won't have issues with other webhooks being triggered.

**P.S.** 
The other issue you may encounter, and I didn't like it at all, is bombardment with old statuses updates. This happens, if you don't answer with 200 statuses explicitly for every webhook trigger.

From their docs:
*If we send a webhook request to your endpoint and your server responds with an HTTP status code other than 200, or if we are unable to deliver the webhook for another reason, we will keep trying with decreasing frequency until the request succeeds, for up to 7 days.*

The workaround was to catch all the possible handling errors on our side and log them to our console, but send 200 for every request as this:
`response.status(200).json({ message: 'Handling finished' })`